# Vertically aligning hyphens and en dash in a compound word

Tags: punctuation, typography

I was wondering if there is a way to make the hyphen and en dash in a compound word appear at the same "height." For instance the style guide I'm following suggests using en dash to reduce the ambiguity in post-apocalyptic-–science fiction movies. It's only a small difference but I was curious if there is a proper way to handle this.

Here is a screenshot of what they suggest it should look like: [image: screenshot from style guide]

And here is what it looks like in my final pdf doc, notice how the hyphen is at one height and the en dash is at another:[image: screenshot from my pdf]

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{book}

\begin{document}
post-apocalyptic--science fiction movies
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could adjust the position with `\raisebox{-0.1ex}{--}`.  Adjust the value `-0.1ex` to suit.

Comment: This issue looks very much font dependent to me; and any fix you apply will be font-dependent as well (e.g. Adobe Garamond has a slightly tilted hyphen that would not allow a fix such as egreg's). Unless you really, *really* have to use an interword en-dash here, you might be better off changing the font altogether or forgetting about the dash (which is not an extremely widespread typographic practice).

Answer (score 7):

You can define a "double hyphen" (if you *really* have to use it)

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\dblhyphen{\mbox{-\kern-.1em-}\discretionary{}{}{}}
\begin{document}
post-apocalyptic\dblhyphen science fiction movies
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

use another font, e.g. Libertine as

```
\usepackage{libertine}% for pdflatex
\usepackage{libertineotf}% for xelatex/lualatex
```

Here the example for `xelatex`

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{libertineotf}
\begin{document}
post-apocalyptic--science fiction movies
\end{document}
```

[image]